# Access to state and payload data together inside ngrx effect

Tags: rxjs, state, ngrx, chaining, payload

I save in ngrx state some widget instance (third party non angular library) and I need to update widget with new params by user action. For this case I dispatch action with new widget params as payload.

It is possible to get payload and state data in same place of effect without additional private field?

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public updateStatistics: Observable<webChatActions.Actions> = this._actions.pipe(
    ofType(Types.UPDATE_STATISTICS),
    map((action: demoActions.UpdateStatistics) => action.payload),
    tap((payload: StatisticsOptions) => console.log(payload)),
    withLatestFrom(this._store),
    map(([action, state]): DemoEffects => state['web-chat']),
    tap((state: WebChatState) => {
    // here I have my state, but also I need payload from tap above
    }),
    catchError((error: Error) => {
        this._logger.error('unable to update feedback widget', error);
        return of(new webChatActions.Service.ShowChatError(error));
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `map` and you have it.

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public updateStatistics: Observable<webChatActions.Actions> = this._actions.pipe(
    ofType(Types.UPDATE_STATISTICS),
    map((action: demoActions.UpdateStatistics) => action.payload),
    tap((payload: StatisticsOptions) => console.log(payload)),
    withLatestFrom(this._store),
    map((): DemoEffects => state['web-chat']),
    tap(([action, state]) => {
      // action.payload 
      // tate['web-chat']
    }),
    catchError((error: Error) => {
        this._logger.error('unable to update feedback widget', error);
        return of(new webChatActions.Service.ShowChatError(error));
    })
);
```